# How to call a function inside a thread?

Tags: sdl-2

I want to perform some load and save operations on another thread (in SDL). To be able to do this I thought of creating a thread and detaching it (letting it end on its own) everytime I call a function that needs to run separately.
But I don't think this is the correct behaviour (or is it?).
Is there any better solution, like creating and using only one thread? And if there is, how can I call my function(s) from it?

Comment: Those silent downvoters...

Comment: Is the SDL2 directly relevant to this? YWhat do you mean by "correct"? Are you concerned about leaking resources? Would C++11's async work for you?

Comment: I'm working with SDL2 and planning to use SDL's semaphores, mutexes, ... So I would like to work only with it. By "correct" I mean if this is the way it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

Use [std::async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async). On most implementations it uses efficient solutions like reusing threads from threadpool.

Answer (score 0):

The Life span of a thread is dependent on the main thread(or parent thread), without a join all children threads would be terminated when the main thread(or parent thread) exit.A thread is tied to the process. You might want to looking into forking a process instead, this would persist even if the parent process exit, but would be could be come a zombie process, with no way of terminating it within the program.